# Not able to add external display with USB 3 to VGA FL2000 chipset in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, external-monitor, vga

**What am I trying?**

Trying to add external display using USB 3 to VGA Fresco Logic 2000 chipset adaptor by compiling a driver and loading a module in the kernel 5.4.0-84-generic in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

**Problem I am facing.**

As soon as I load the modules, the screen flickers, and `lsmod` shows `used_by  1` but there's no display on the target device and the `used by` in `fl2000` goes back to 0.

Driver Link: https://github.com/klogg/fl2000_drm

```
lsusb         
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1d5c:2000 Fresco Logic FL2000/FL2000DX VGA/DVI/HDMI Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
fl2000                 32768  0
```

**Kernel Logs**

```
[ 1301.640870] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth7a45700) entered disabled state
[ 1330.244677] INFO: task kworker/7:3:351 blocked for more than 845 seconds.
[ 1330.244684]       Tainted: G        W  OE     5.4.0-84-generic #94-Ubuntu
[ 1330.244687] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1330.244690] kworker/7:3     D    0   351      2 0x80004000
[ 1330.244703] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
[ 1330.244706] Call Trace:
[ 1330.244717]  __schedule+0x2e3/0x740
[ 1330.244723]  schedule+0x42/0xb0
[ 1330.244728]  schedule_timeout+0x10e/0x160
[ 1330.244734]  ? kobj_kset_leave+0x51/0x60
[ 1330.244738]  ? __kobject_del+0x41/0x50
[ 1330.244743]  wait_for_completion+0xb1/0x120
[ 1330.244748]  ? wake_up_q+0x70/0x70
[ 1330.244756]  i2c_del_adapter+0x240/0x300
[ 1330.244768]  fl2000_i2c_adapter_release+0x22/0x26 [fl2000]
[ 1330.244774]  release_nodes+0x19a/0x1e0
[ 1330.244779]  devres_release_all+0x3f/0x50
[ 1330.244784]  device_release_driver_internal+0x10f/0x1d0
[ 1330.244787]  device_release_driver+0x12/0x20
[ 1330.244790]  bus_remove_device+0xe1/0x150
[ 1330.244795]  device_del+0x165/0x370
[ 1330.244799]  usb_disconnect+0x16e/0x270
[ 1330.244803]  hub_port_connect+0x7d/0x850
[ 1330.244808]  ? usb_set_device_state+0x9b/0x170
[ 1330.244812]  port_event+0x502/0x780
[ 1330.244816]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
[ 1330.244820]  hub_event+0x152/0x390
[ 1330.244825]  ? psi_avgs_work+0x64/0xd0
[ 1330.244831]  process_one_work+0x1eb/0x3b0
[ 1330.244836]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
[ 1330.244841]  kthread+0x104/0x140
[ 1330.244846]  ? process_one_work+0x3b0/0x3b0
[ 1330.244849]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
[ 1330.244853]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[ 1361.329676] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered blocking state
[ 1361.329682] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered disabled state
[ 1361.329973] device veth6683171 entered promiscuous mode
[ 1361.330384] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered blocking state
[ 1361.330389] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered forwarding state
[ 1361.331506] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered disabled state
[ 1361.823778] eth0: renamed from veth4e9e9b8
[ 1361.852224] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth6683171: link becomes ready
[ 1361.852402] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered blocking state
[ 1361.852407] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered forwarding state
[ 1363.235808] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered disabled state
[ 1363.236620] veth4e9e9b8: renamed from eth0
[ 1363.510263] br-f29d10b4f721: port 1(veth6683171) entered disabled state
[ 1363.515881] device veth6683171 left promiscuous mode
```

Comment: did you find any solution yet?